# How do I solve this question using basic counting rules?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In how many ways can two representatives from the Boyer school be chosen to be on a committee? One of the representatives must be a student, and one must be a faculty member.

faculty=40
students=214

> > How do I go about this problem? Should I be using subtraction and addition rules? And how do I use them?

Comment: You should be using the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 0):

The addition rule is used when both actions cannot be done at the same time. In this case, you can choose a student among 214 students independently with choosing a faculty member among 40 faculty members, which mean that using rule of product as mentioned above by @N. F. Taussig is the way to go